# Should this Grasslin UWZ48-L hour counter in my septic pump box be rolling or ticking over?

Tags: electrical, septic

Should this counter be moving forward if it is working properly?  Would it tick 1 hour at a time (tick at the hour) or slowly roll forward minute by minute (slow roll)?

[image]

Background: My septic alarmed yesterday.  I thought it was because our washer has this annoying habit of refilling to try to balance a load, and had done so probably 5 or 10 times for a load of blankets; just figured that would fill the system and that we'd be caught up by now.  But 25h later we're still alarmed.  Have deliberately not used very much water since then so I'd figure it would clear by now.  Anyway I noticed this ticker has been stuck on this number 0093961 for about two hours now (since I took notice, may have been stuck longer).  Seems wrong.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hour meters aside.....is your pump pumping or not?

Comment: It will only be moving when the pumps are running.  I googled for more info and found this must be an older PS11 model because newer models have the hour counter and a event counter, but it’s unclear eithers exact purpose.  I suspect the pumps run based on the timer, which appears to be an interval timer.  It’s also unclear based on pictures or online documentation what the alarm condition means exactly.

Comment: limo-driver how could i tell?  my understanding was that it pumped for a period once every six hours so how could i catch it when it was pumping and what would i look for?

Comment: You might have to remove lid from lift station to verify water levels.    Your alarm is most likely a high water level indicator.....which means pump is not pumping.

Comment: Update: I went and checked late in the evening and it had rolled forward to 93970.  This leads me to believe it rolls forward all at once, number of hours since last pump.  Also, the alarm was clear this morning.

Comment: You might want to adjust the timer setting for when your pump runs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is an hours meter, it is not a timer.  (The Omron device next to it is a timer, capable of various modes of operation depending how it's installed.)  The hours meter is like the odometer on a car.

The display is hours to two decimal points.  If it is working properly it should be ticking every .01 hours, or 36 seconds, when the load runs - probably the pump motor.

If the tank is alarming and it's not moving, that indicates the motor isn't running or maybe short cycling, so there's a problem - couldn't say what.

This time of year (summer here) my first guess is heat, maybe the overloads for the pump motor were preventing it from running during the heat of the day but came back online when things cooled at night.  But that's just a guess.